# Error: .post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, routes

there are several issues with the same theme, but I could not solve my problem.

```
Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
at Route.(anonymous function) [as post] (/home/kevin/proyectoApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196:15)
at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as post] (/home/kevin/proyectoApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:481:19)
at module.exports (/home/kevin/proyectoApp/app/rutas.js:7:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/proyectoApp/index.js:21:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
at startup (node.js:141:18)
at node.js:1003:3
```

Index.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var morgan=require('morgan')
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var methodOverride=require('method-override');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/local');


app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


//Endpoints
require('./app/rutas.js')(app);


var server=app.listen(3001,function () {
var host = "localhost";
var port = server.address().port;

console.log('servidor escuchando en http://%s:%s', host, port);});
module.exports=app;
```

rutas.js

```
var Controller=require('./controller.js');
var User=require('./models/user.js');

module.exports=function(app){

app.get('/user/all',Controller.Read);

app.put('/user/all/:todo_id',Controller.Update);

app.post('/user/all',Controller.Create);

app.delete('/user/all/todo_id',Controller.Delete);


app.get('/',function(req,res){
console.log("Este si carga");
res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});
 }
```

user.js

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var Schemausuario=new Schema({
nombre:String,
apellido:String,
username:{type:String,requiere:true,unique:true}
});

var User=mongoose.model('User',Schemausuario);

module.exports=User;
```

controller.js

```
var User=require('./models/user.js');

var Create=function (req,res){
var nombre=req.body.nombre;
var apellido=req.body.apellido;
var nick=req.body.username;
console.log("Datos"+nombre+apellido+nick);
User.create({
nombre:nombre,
apellido:apellido,
username:nick

},function(err,usr){

if( err) console.log("Error al crear el usuario");
else{
    console.log("Usuario creado correctamente");
}
});

User.find({},function(err,user){
if(err) console.log("Hay un error al buscar los usuarios");
else{
    console.log("Los usuarios encontrados son "+user)
       res.json(user);
            }        
});

};


var Read=function (req,res){

User.find({},function(err,user){
if(err) return console.log("error="+err);
else{
       res.json(user);
            }        
});
};



var Update=function(req,res){
User.update( {_id : req.params.todo_id},
                {$set:{nombre : req.body.nombre,apellido:    req.body.apellido, username: req.body.username}}, 
                function(err, persona) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

            // Obtine y devuelve todas las personas tras crear una de     ellas
            User.find(function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    res.send("Ha habido un error"+err)
                console.log("Se va a enviar "+persona)
                res.json(user);
            });
        });
};


var Delete=function(req,res){

  User.remove({
    _id: req.params.todo_id
}, function(err, todo) {
    if(err){
        res.send("Hay un error hdp"+err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Usuario eliminado correctamente")
    }
    });

    User.find({},function(err, todos) {
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(todos);
    });
};

module.exports={
Create:Create,
Update:Update,
Read:Read,
Delete:Delete
}
```

I use the version "express", "^ 4.13.3"

can you help me? thanks.
any other details that I'll upload it finds omitted.
any other details that I'll upload it finds omitted.

Comment: I solved this problem by following the details included in [this Stack Overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69828684/14193416)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
app.post('/user/all',Controller.Create);
```

You try for:

```
app.post('/user/all', function(req, res){
  Controller.Create
});
```

Comment: @KevinAB Hi could you explain why this won't work: `app.post('/user/all',Controller.Create);`

Comment: I don't see the problem with this: `Controller.Create = function(req, res) { ... }`

Comment: I wonder how `Controller. Create` worked in the 2nd case given that the `Create function in controller.js expects request, response object to be passed as params`. Shouldn't this be `Controller.Create(req,res)`. I might be missing some internal functioning here though :)

Comment: can u explain this??

Comment: @Subburaj by using your solution that error was fixed, but other functionality does not work.there was some error in exporting and importing, now that's work fine with `Controller.create`. Thanks

Comment: @btzr if we use `'/user/all/', Controller.Create` we are not even passing the req,res parameters.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.

Comment: check middleware names correctly referenced or not

Answer (score 41):

In my case it was because I had a misspelling between the router and controller file. Check both so that they match, the error `.POST() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]` has nothing to do with the real problem.

Comment: You're right it has nothing to do with the real problem. For me I was exporting the function wrongly.

Comment: For me, it was where I forgot to rename the new function in the router when I copy-pasted.

Comment: Absolutely right! For me, I created `model.updateOne` but added `model.update` to the router.

Answer (score 15):

You are only missing

> module.exports = app, 
>   or whatever you are exporting. This happened to me many times.

Comment: That is the exact issue with this particular error type. There's an export missing, probably in the controller file.

Comment: "It's the little things that kill." — Bush, "Little Things"

Comment: One thing to add here: *Check for function names when copy-pasting*!

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when I declared the function in routes but forgot to define it in the controller.

Answer (score 5):

You want to be sure to check that your spellings are correct for the export and the import. Also make sure your middleware are properly exported and imported.

From the code you are sharing, you should export each middleware individually as
`exports.Create`, `exports.Update` etc. Setting up your export this way will make it possible to access it the way you are currently accessing it view the `Controller` variable in your `rutas.js` file.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was Destructuring the export while importing.

if you did `module.exports = something`, you need to do `const something = require('./dir')`
But if you did `module.exports = { something }`, you need to do `const { something } = require('./dir')`

Answer (score 3):

Another case, which I ran into.  I was importing from the controller a method called

```
const { createTrade } = require(...)
```

But I also had

```
exports.createTrade = async (..) => { ...
```

In another part of this file I referenced the createTrade from the import but it was confused about using the exports.createTrade or the imported one.  I had to switch to

```
const controller = require(...)

controller.createTrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Always ensure the export name is the same as the import name

```js
//Function Exported
exports.isAuthenticatedUser = catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, next) => {
}


//Function Imported
const {isAuthenticatedUser} = require('../middlewares/auth');
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a simple, stupid typo.

I had `module.export = {` instead of `module.exports = {`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue the way i resolved it was i did comment every post command and then i tested all the post commands one by one and in the 2nd last command when i checked routuer there was a typo error and that was that function wasnt called.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was due to a circular dependency in the file - file A imported functions from file B, but file B imported functions from file A.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've encountered this error when I have deleted a function in my controller.js file but forgot to remove it in the router definition.

for eg,

```
router.get('/', controller.getUsers);
```

So, in the above code, I've deleted that getUsers() function in the controller.js file but I still used it in the route definition. So after removing this useless route the problem gets solved. Hope this error helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didnot exported the function of controller

Comment: This answer is more suitable as a comment, try enhancing your answer by providing an example on how to solve OP's problem. (e.g. how to export a function and which function exactly.)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when you mistakenly import functions in the wrong way, or may be a spelling mistake
Both the **controller** and the **route** are in some trouble.

I encountered this when I was exporting a function from the controller which was all good.

```js
exports.addCategory = (req,res) => {}
```

but when I was importing it in the routes I was doing

```js
const addCategory = require('../Controllers/Category')
```

instead

```js
const {addCategory) = require('../Controllers/Category')
```

you see that curly braces around addCategory while importing
So, I was importing the entire function, which was wrong

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem adding

```js
module.exports = new ExampleController();
```

just adding `new`.

Answer (score 0):

do not export your controller like this

```
module.exports.createPost = () => {..}
```

instead of export like this

```
module.exports = {
    createPost,
}
```

and import the controller like this,

```
postRouter.post("/createNew_post", postControllers.createPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, this was my mistake:

Controller:

```
module.exports = cargarArchivo;
```

Route:

```
const { cargarArchivo } = require('../controllers/uploads');
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

router.post( '/', cargarArchivo )
```

Error:

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
```

SOLUTION: In the controller change:

```
module.exports = cargarArchivo;
```

For:

```
module.exports = {
  cargarArchivo
}
```

The problems is I'm exporting the constant as a constant instead exporting it as a property in the controller, then importing it as a property. It has to match both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the Controller Method Name Work For me. Try it also

Answer (score 0):

I stuck for an hour then I resolved these issues, whenever you got these errors then you should understand that you have created a different name convention in admin and AdminMediator. I solved these issues, when I clicked on the required APIs in admin, it doesn't direct me to the desired API in AdminMediator, then I understood why this error occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case in the controllers the function login was not defined,
but trying to access

For Example:

```js
router.post('/user/login', userController.login)
```

Answer (score 0):

*In route.js*, instead of importing:

```js
**var Controller=require('./controller.js');
```

Try this:

```js
var { Controller } = require('./contoller.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also quite possible you have a route that is defined but not being used, try looking for that route and deleting both the route and controller

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Remove/comment all other routes which you haven't yet defined (Let's say in your controller).

In my case it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32671503)

Answer (score 0):

the error I was getting is :

```
Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
```

and this was my file:
[image: my code at that time]
userController file from where I was importing
[image]

the mistake I was doing at that time is importing 2 entities from a file separately instead of de-structuring

this will fix my error
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! It would even be more helpful to provide the code in text form, not in form of images / screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code I got the same issues and I found 3 valid solutions if your using module.exports.

when I tried to print the imports from my controller I found it is return empty object `{}` . so the solutions are

Solution 1: Cross check the name of the files where you exporting and where you importing it in your path.

Solution 2:  use require.resolve("...your import path").

example for solution 1 :

before:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const createToDo = require("../controllers/CreateToDoController")
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("<h1>Welcome to Homepage</h1>");
})
console.log('todo iss', createToDo);
router.post("/createtodo",(req,res)=>createToDo(res,req));
module.exports = router;
```

after:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const createToDo = require.resolve("../controllers/CreateToDoController")
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("<h1>Welcome to Homepage</h1>");
})
console.log('todo iss', createToDo);
router.post("/createtodo",(req,res)=>createToDo(res,req));
module.exports = router;
```

Solution 3:

Wrap the controller function inside callback. Better to use arrow function to make it one line:

here is the code before change:
Todocontroller.js

```
//importing model
const toDoModel = require('../models/ToDoModel');

//creating controller function
const createToDoController = async (req,res)=>{
    try{
    const {title,toDoTasks} = req.body;

    if(!title) //input validation
    { 
        throw new Error("Please provide the title");
    }
    const newToDo = await toDoModel.create({ title, tasks:toDoTasks?toDoTasks:[] });
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: "User Created Successfully",
        newToDo,
      });
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Unable to perform create operation",
            error: err
        })
        res.send(err.message);
    } 

}
module.exports = createToDoController;
```

router.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const createToDo = require("../controllers/CreateToDoController")
router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("<h1>Welcome to Homepage</h1>");
})
console.log(`todo iss ${createToDo}`);
router.post("/createtodo",createToDo);
module.exports = router;
```

I have change the line from
`router.post("/createtodo",createToDo);`
to
`router.post("/createtodo",(req,res)=>createToDo(res,req));`

I don't understand why this is happening but yeah this is only solution working for me. if you got better solutions please mention in discussions :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `{}` around the importing variable was sufficient to solve the error:

```
const {registerUser}=require("../controllers/userController");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have misspelled `controller.create` in controller or routes file

Answer (score 0):

Recently i got the same error at first i want to share the error,which i got and then i will explain the solution.

[in the image i have shown the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnlMY.png)

SOLUTION: 1.At first check if you did any typo.

2.Always be consistant throught your code(i were not consistant this was my fault)

3. don't mix up the require and import syntax if you are using require you should use require and if you are using ES6(import) use ES6 throughout your code

   ```
                     **MY MISTEAK**
   ```

```js
import userService from '../services/user.service.js'
import jwtProvider from '../config/jwtProvider.js'
import cartService from '../services/cart.service.js'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

export const register = async(req,res) => {
   try {
     const user = await userService.createUser(req.body)
     const jwt = jwtProvider.generatejwtToken(user._id)

     await cartService.createCart(user)

     return res.status(200).send({jwt,message:"registered successfully"})
   } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({error:error.message})
   }
}

 const login = async(req,res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    try{
      const user = await userService.getUserByEmail(email)

      if(!user){
        return res.status(404).send({message:"user not found with email",email})
      }
      const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
      if(!isPasswordValid){
        return res.status(401).send({})
      }
        const jwtToken =  jwtProvider.generatejwtToken(user._id)
        return res.status(200).json({jwtToken,message:"loggedIn successfully"})

    }catch(error){
        return res.status(500).send({error:error.message})
    }
}

export default login
```

```
          ROUTER CODE
```

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import authController from '../controller/auth.controller.js'



const router = Router()
router.post('/signup',authController.register);
router.post('/login',authController.login)

export default router
```

```
                **AFTER DEBUGGING MY CODE**
                  **SOLVED MY PROBLEM**
```

```js
import userService from '../services/user.service.js'
import jwtProvider from '../config/jwtProvider.js'
import cartService from '../services/cart.service.js'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

 const register = async(req,res) => {
   try {
     const user = await userService.createUser(req.body)
     const jwt = jwtProvider.generatejwtToken(user._id)

     await cartService.createCart(user)

     return res.status(200).send({jwt,message:"registered successfully"})
   } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({error:error.message})
   }
}

 const login = async(req,res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    try{
      const user = await userService.getUserByEmail(email)

      if(!user){
        return res.status(404).send({message:"user not found with email",email})
      }
      const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
      if(!isPasswordValid){
        return res.status(401).send({})
      }
        const jwtToken =  jwtProvider.generatejwtToken(user._id)
        return res.status(200).json({jwtToken,message:"loggedIn successfully"})

    }catch(error){
        return res.status(500).send({error:error.message})
    }
}

export{
  register,
  login
}
```

```
                 CORRECTED ROUTER CODE
```

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import { register,login } from '../controller/auth.controller.js';


const router = Router()
router.post('/signup', register);
router.post('/login', login)

export default router
```

```
            **KEY POINT WHAT I HAVE CHANGED**
```

1. In my controller i have changed only export, previously i exporting first controller by default and another on initialiation time
2. In my router i have changed importing statement i imported that by destructuring and insted of using .(dot) operator i have directly call that
3. After doing these two steps my problem has been resolved.

***HOPE MY EFFORT WILL HELP SOMEONE****

Answer (score 0):

My issue turned out to be that some of my callbacks were async functions, which evaluate to a Promise, not a function. The solution was to wrap the async code in a non-async function call. I did this in the `module.exports` object:

```
module.exports = {
  myCallback: (req, res) => { myCallbackAsync(req, res); },
  // ...
}
```

but it could also be done within the function itself by wrapping the async code in an async sub-function or IIFE and calling that within the callback.

Answer (score -1):

yes Subburaj is correct,
Implement in app.js

```
app.post('/sign', function (req, res) {
    LoginController.authenticate
});
```

this could be solve the problem